# Terminal Mac OS show A^[[C^[[C^[[B^[[D when press arrow keyboard

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, ruby-on-rails-5

I try to use gem `pry` to debug ruby on rails app, but when system stop on `binding.pry`, when I press arrow key such as `left`, `right`, `above`, terminal didn't turn left or turn right, it only show character like `A^[[C^[[C^[[B^[[D`. So please help me.

[image]